# while creating controller am getting error like this can you please guide me

Tags: model-view-controller

unable to retrieve metadata for `MvcApplication1.Models.Student`
unable to cast of object type

`system.Data.Entity.core.objects.objectContext` to type `system.data.objects.objectcontext`

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: What controller? What environment? What language or framework? Please, consider enhancing your question with more details. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask well posted questions

Comment: Am using MVC4 using IDE VS2012 and Am trying to create student controller, please find the below student class file and context file using entity frame work code first spproch.